# Somebody can explain how works AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to make something like the image posted, but that suppose the viewpager is scrollable with the recyclerView, the header is a simple Linear/Relative Layout and this will be static, the fab same (not scrollable) but is not working.

I posted my layout below

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/layout_view_pager"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_labels"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
                android:background="@color/brand_green"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="43sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/actionbar_balance_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"          android:textSize="13sp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/chime_sign"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        app:iconFontColor="@android:color/white"
                        app:iconFontSize="26sp"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_icon_mm"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@color/brand_dark_green"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/header_labels"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the viewpager is scrollable with the recyclerView"

Comment: yes, when you start to scrolling the recyclerView, the viewpager is scrolling too with the collapsingtoolbarlayout (if is possible) something like a header for the listview

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've set `app:layout_collapseMode` to `pin` for both `RelativeLayout` and `Toolbar` which will not show any effect. Setting `app:layout_collapseMode` to pin for any view will not change the view's height when scrolling takes place. To change a view's height when scrolling takes place, you need to set `app:layout_collapseMode` to `parallax`.

Secondly, set a specified height for your `AppBarLayout`. Setting `WRAP_CONTENT` will not work properly. You need to set specific dimensions like 180dp.

Thirdly, according to your question you wanted the Viewpager to be scrollable with the `RecyclerView`. Your code doesn't work the way you intended it to be. If you want the `ViewPager` to be scrollable with `RecyclerView` then you need to remove the `RecyclerView` from the xml code and add it to a separate xml code file. Then you need to create a `Fragment` or two (according to your need), add the `Fragment` in the `ViewPager` and instantiate the `RecyclerView` in there. This `Fragment` will also be responsible for inflating data in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `wrap_content` for the height of the `AppBarLayout`, I have done it in my apps. There's also no requirement that he use Fragments at all. It's not clear from the question what he means when he says the "viewpager is scrollable with the recyclerView". He could mean that he wants the ViewPager to act as if it were the first item in the RecyclerView.